# Popup context menu on ListView hold

Tags: java, android

I have a code sample got from the internet and the code goes like this

```
ListView lv1;
lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.custom_list);
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id)  {
        // print toast
    }
});
```

Well I want to show context menu on list item click and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to clear what you are trying to ask for, so more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. I also indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting.  Good luck!

Comment: It's not really clear from your question. Would you like the context menu to appear on click or on long press? (You can edit your own question to clear this intention too)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu).

Create popup.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_action1"
          android:icon="@drawable/menu_action1"
          android:title="@string/menu_action1" />

    ...
</menu>
```

and add this to `onItemClick`:

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
// this = your activity
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
popup.inflate(R.menu.actions);
popup.show();
```

In addition your Activity should implements [OnMenuItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener.html) so you can get menu click callback.